# Saving chat transcripts in nosql databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm building a chat server app using node.js.

I need to save chat transcripts on the database and would like
to play with nosql database like mongodb. If i was in relational db world, i would
create users, chat_sessions and chat_messages tables and, for every new message, i'd
append new record in chat_messages table.

Which is the best approach in nosql?

Do i have to create a chat_session document and, inside of it, create 
a chat_messages structure that is updated for every new message or
is there a better way to do it for nosql/mongodb?

Comment: NoSQL != MongoDB.  If you're speaking specifically of MongoDB, you should rephrase your question to indicate that. Because the solution will be very different in a key/value store, versus a document store, versus a big table store.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a similar approach and insert each new message as a separate document into the collection (possibly one for each room or channel).

Documents in MongoDB have a 16mb limit so storing the entire history in one document, which grows in an unbounded fashion, would be a bad choice.

You can de-normalize usernames and store them on the messages themselves to avoid querying two tables (this would likely be a join in a relational database).

It may make sense to split the data into multiple databases rather than collections (per room, channel, whatever) because currently mongodb has a database level write lock. This would allow you to achieve greater write concurrency with mongodb and node.js.